# Is there a function to read tf record shard files directly into a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, dataset, tfrecord

I've downloaded the ucf101 dataset, which is split into 10 tf record shards (with file names such as "ucf101-train.tfrecord-00003-of-00010").

I want to use the dataset as a numpy array, so is there a way to either combine all the shards into one tfrecord file to run it through tfds.as_numpy or directly convert it into a numpy array?